# How to use Push() to save multiple entries to Firebase without write conflict?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not too familiar with using dictionary objects, and am trying to use this code to save some basic info to Firebase database when a user creates a new account. So far this is what I have, but it doesn't write any data. Could this be that I need to already have the directory created in the database, or is there something else going on?

I copied the syntax directly from the documentation, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. FirebaseLogin is another script that I'm pulling the userID and email from.

```
public class User
{
    public string uid;
    public string email;
    public int round = 1;
    public int lives = 3;
    public int level = 1;
    public int currentScore = 0;
    public int totalScore = 0;

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string uid, string email, int round, int lives, int level, int currentScore, int totalScore)
    {
        this.uid = FirebaseLogin.currentUserId;
        this.email = FirebaseLogin.currentEmail;
        this.round = round;
        this.lives = lives;
        this.level = level;
        this.currentScore = currentScore;
        this.totalScore = totalScore;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Object> ToDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Object> result = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
        result["uid"] = uid;
        result["email"] = email;
        result["round"] = round;
        result["lives"] = lives;
        result["level"] = level;
        result["currentScore"] = currentScore;
        result["totalScore"] = totalScore;

        return result;
    }
}

public void AddNewUserData(string uid, string email, int round, int lives, int level, int currentScore, int totalScore)
{
    DatabaseReference reference = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    string key = reference.Child("users").Push().Key;
    User entry = new User(uid, email, round, lives, level, currentScore, totalScore);
    Dictionary<string, Object> entryValues = entry.ToDictionary();
    Dictionary<string, Object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    childUpdates["/test1/" + key] = entryValues;
    childUpdates["/test2/" + uid + "/" + key] = entryValues;

    reference.UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates);
}
```

Comment: "Could this be that I need to already have the directory created in the database" Firebase automatically creates paths as you write values, and automatically removes empty paths when you delete values. There is no need to pre-create the paths themselves or clean them up.

Comment: Thank you Frank van Puffelen. Do you have any idea what could be causing this? Or if not can you suggest a good way to write multiple entries without causing write conflicts? After a week on this I finally am comfortable creating database entries using SetValueAsync and SetRawJsonValueAsync, but when writing multiple entries it creates an issue.
Following the documentation I've  used both transactions and dictionary objects to try to follow their syntax, and debugging is showing the value updating so I'm not sure at what point the issue is here.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working, but just wanted to explain that "creating the parent nodes" won't be the reason.